# Movie where various people gain powers such as seeing the future and healing diseases

Tags: identify-this-movie

In this film, some guys gain powers.

I remember that there is one that can see the future, a woman that can heal diseases, and one that can control the milk. The last one becomes evil and kills them all, but this turns out to be the vision of the one who can see the future.

Following this vision, the other take revenge against the evil one before everything happens.

Note, it's not *Chronicle*.

Comment: *control the milk*: Er, what?

Comment: Did you mean *control the mind* and that she is the one who goes evil?

Comment: It's milk, I remember this plot too. Some kind of talent show... I think i got it. Answer incoming.

Comment: Was he called Moo-Man?

Comment: No, it was specifically milk. There were a bunch of super powers, and some of them were rather more useful than others.

Comment: I have this picture in my mind of Dumbledore fighting Voldemort at the end of [Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373889/) but using milk instead of water.

Comment: It's silly how much of this overlaps with [Heroes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0813715/), and [The 4400](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389564/) before that. Other than, y'know, that weird milk thing.

Comment: I'm not sure about the other powers, but I think I found the one that controls milk: https://youtu.be/1eFDra1XimA

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are thinking about [Episode 2.6](http://e4-misfits.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_6) of the series [Misfits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1548850/).

The power to control milk is called [Lactokinesis](http://e4-misfits.wikia.com/wiki/Lactokinesis).

After Milk Man reveals superpowers to the world, he gets ignored for the main cast, a bunch of delinquents with better powers. Milk man starts killing people with his lactokinesis, but one of the Misfits travels back in time to before Milk Man goes to the media. They then beat or kill him, it's a bit vague.

Comment: Control... the milk. I don't even know where to start. If this is the answer, *well done*!

Comment: @andrew he lost the super power lottery that is the Misfits. Then again, he was pretty damn good at murdering people until someone lactose found out and stopped him. He made people choke on their breakfast with his mind.

Comment: I remember that episode. That show was great. Other powers included switching sexes, inducing people to rape you by physical contact, and some weird deal where this guy perceived the world to be Grand Theft Auto.

Comment: @AndrewMartin It's definitely the answer, as soon as I read the question I recognised the show although it is a british TV show not a film (or as americans call it movie)

Comment: Well he is not one of their social workers so they probably just beat him up, the social workers always end up dead.  A sort of running joke after awhile.  Great show, and yes, this is what I thought of when I saw the Question

Comment: "That's the mozarella wrapping itself around your central cortex"... LOL, what a line... :-D